# CORS request in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-domain, cors

I need to make a post request using Javascript that should be working in Internet explorer. Client and server are located on the different servers and use different protocols.

I have tried 2 different ways

1)

```
                    var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
                    var user = document.getElementById('username').value;
                    var psw = document.getElementById('password').value;
                    var params = "username="+user+"&password="+psw+"&system=telenetweb";
                    xdr.open("post", url);

                        xdr.onprogress = function () {
                        //Progress
                      };

                      xdr.ontimeout = function () { 
                        //Timeout
                      };

                      xdr.onerror = function () { 
                        //Error Occured
                      };

                      xdr.onload = function() {
                        //success(xdr.responseText);
                      }

                      setTimeout(function () {
                        xdr.send(params);
                      }, 0);
```

but it does not work as I am making request from http to https.

2)

```
            var http;
            try {
                http = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                  http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (E) {
                  http = false;
                }
            }
              if (!http && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
                http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }

            var user = document.getElementById('username').value;
            var psw = document.getElementById('password').value;
            var params = "username="+user+"&password="+psw+"&system=telenetweb";

            http.open("POST", url, true);
            http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
            http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
            http.send(params);
```

This works in Chrome but not in IE as IE does not append Origin header to the request.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior of MSIE clearly depends on the version. I don't recommend you to use [XDomainRequest, because it is very limited](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx), so it does not worth the effort. The [XHR2 is supported from MSIE version 10](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2), you should use that, it works exactly the same way as in chrome or firefox. If you want CORS with a lower MSIE version, I think you should forget it.

If you really need it by low version MSIE (which I doubt) you can use JSONP, which has limitations too, but maybe it can solve your problem.